# How to convert List<String[]> into List<MyObject>?

Tags: java, string, csv, object

I have got a List from a csv file. This csv file is populated this way:

```
_Name_ |_Surname_|_Sex_
_nam1_ | _sur1_  | _s1_
_nam2_ | _sur2_  | _s2_
```

So i do:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file.csv"));
List<String[]> myEntries = reader.readAll();
```

Now, I want to create another list, of type MyObject like:

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

where the class MyObject contains:

```
private String name;
private String surname;
private String sex;
```

with their get and set. 
And what's inside the first list shall be moved into:

```
list.setName();
list.setSurname();
list.setSex();
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can try:

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

for(String[] entry : myEntries){
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    //assign values to properties of our object
    obj.setName(entry[0]);
    obj.setSurname(entry[1]);
    obj.setSex(entry[2]);

    //add object to list
    list.add(obj);
}
```

I hope that helps

Comment: I think you need to skip the first row, as it contains meta information.

Answer (score 1):

If MyObject.class has a constructor that works with your 3 informations than you can use:

```
for (String[] item : myEntries) {
        list.add(new MyObject(item[0], item[1], item[2]);
    }
```

Otherwise try this:

```
for (String[] item : myEntries) {
        MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
        myObj.setName(item[0]);
        myObj.setSurname(item[1]);
        myObj.setSex(item[2]);
        list.add(myObj);
    }
```

Comment: what if my array list contained 1000 strings?

Comment: @Marco I don't understand what you mean? Your ArrayList can only contain objects from the class MyObject.

Comment: mean 1000 columns. Name, surname, age, sex, height, weight, country, birthday, ....

Comment: @Marco Than you have to call every Setter for its own or you can create a contructor in MyObject.class which accepts that you can pass your String array.

Comment: I think you need to skip the first row, as it contains meta information.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a matching constructor (or converter or whatever) in your object class, you can use stream operations.

```
public class MyObject {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String sex;

    public MyObject(){}

    public static MyObject fromStringArr(String[] csvVals) {
        assert csvVals != null && csvVals.length >= 3;   

        MyObject m = new MyObject();
        m.name = csvVals[0];
        m.surname = csvVals[1];
        m.sex = csvVals[2];
        return m;
    }

    //Getters and setters for MyObject...
    //....
}
```

Then you can read straight into your object type.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file.csv"));
List<MyObject> myEntries = reader.readAll().stream().skip(1).map(MyObject::fromStringArr).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I think you need to skip the first row, as it contains meta information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `MyObject` has a constructor such as:

```
public final class MyObject {

    private final String name, surname, sex;

    public MyObject(final String name, final String surname, final String sex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.sex = sex;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = reader.readAll()
                                 .stream()
                                 .map(entry -> new MyObject(entry[0], entry[1], entry[2]))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alternative using a spliterator:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = StreamSupport.stream(csvReader::spliterator, ORDERED, true)
                               .map(entry -> new MyObject(entry[0], entry[1], entry[2]))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I think you need to skip the first row, as it contains meta information.

Comment: @gevorg I believe there is an option when you construct the `CSVReader` to specify the number of lines to skip

Comment: Yes, you are correct [CSVReader](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html) the `line` parameter is just for that :)

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1** - Make sure you initialize [`CSVReader`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html) properly.

According to [API documentation](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html) with `CSVReader(Reader reader, char separator, char quotechar, int line)` you can skip the first line using the proper constructor, also you need to specify the `quotechar` and `separator` so it knows the format of data.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file.csv"), ',', '_', 1);
```

**Step 2** - Collect objects using [`java.util.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

```
myEntries.forEach(entity -> {
    MyObject object = new MyObject();

    object.setName(entity[0]);
    object.setSurname(entity[1]);
    object.setSex(entity[2]);

    list.add(object);
});
```

or better define proper constructor for it like this:

```
public MyObject(String name, String surname, String sex) {
    setName(name);
    setSurname(surname);
    setSex(sex);
}
```

and simplify loop:

```
myEntries.forEach(entity -> list.add(new MyObject(entity[0], entity[1], entity[2]));
```

**Question** - What if you have 1000 columns?

As [arizzle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6391367/arizzle) mentioned, it is not a good idea to have 1000 fields in one class and for that case you better use `HashMap` instead of `MyObject`.

Comment: what if my array list contained 1000 strings?

Comment: @Marco you mean 1000 columns or 1000 rows?

Comment: I mean 1000 columns. 
Name, surname, age, sex, height, weight, country, birthday, ....

Comment: @Marco for that case you need parse meta info also, look updated answer.

Comment: @Marco if you have 1000 columns, I don't think you want to be storing all of that information in one class with 1000 setters and 1000 getters....

Comment: @arizzle you are right, it is not a good idea to store 1000 fields in one class, I suggest to use `HashMap` for that case.

Comment: @Marco I updated answer, with proper suggestion and question answer.